# How can I move the cursor to an input field?

Tags: focus, dart

How can I move the cursor to an input field in Dart?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a reference to the [InputElement](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/InputElement.html) in `input`:

```dart
input.focus();
```

does the trick.  You can get that reference through a call to `query()`, for example:

```dart
input = query('#input_id');
input.focus();
```

or perhaps you created the element yourself:

```dart
var input = new InputElement();
document.body.children.add(input);
input.focus();
```

Comment: It was not working. I see the cursor at the end of the url. I use the latest darteditor on ubuntu 12.4  64 bit.

Comment: It definitely works for me.  I'm guessing you don't have your `<script>` tags set up properly.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>W08</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="w08.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="w08.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Do you have the `dart.js` bootstrap script in `packages/browser/dart.js` relative to the HTML file?  Is the generated input field showing up, and just not receiving focus?  If that isn't showing up, then your Dart code isn't running.

Comment: I created a new application with the sample and added the three lines of dart code. The input field shows up. The dart.js file is there.

Comment: import 'dart:html';  
  
  
var input = new InputElement();  
  
void main() {  
  query("#sample_text_id")  
    ..text = "Click me!"  
    ..onClick.listen(reverseText);  
  
//  var input = new InputElement();  
  document.body.children.add(input);  
  input.focus();  
}  
  
void reverseText(MouseEvent event) {  
  var text = query("#sample_text_id").text;  
  var buffer = new StringBuffer();  
  for (int i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  
    buffer.write(text[i]);  
  }  
  query("#sample_text_id").text = buffer.toString();  
  input.focus();  
}

Comment: Ah, I just set up Dart Editor and see the same thing.  It's an issue with how Dart Editor launches Dartium.  If you press enter in the URL field or click the reload button with the mouse, then the input will receive focus.  For some reason on first launch through the editor, the focus works differently.

Comment: See my last comment.  `input.focus();` does work in any real-world scenario.  This is just an issue with launching Dartium through the Dart Editor.  It seems that after the code runs, the focus is always placed in the URL bar.  The focus *is* going to the input element, but then being taken for reasons outside your control.  Again, this isn't an issue once you deploy, and for now, just press refresh or enter.